# How to reach the third dropdown menu directly from the first one without choosing from the second

Tags: javascript, html

I have three cascading dropdown menus, so far I have managed to reach the second one depending on the first, and the third one depending on the second, now I want to reach the third one depending on the first directly.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let region = document.getElementById("region");
  let city = document.getElementById("city");
  let theOptions = document.getElementById("theOptions");
  let dropdown = {
    "region1": {
      "city1": ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
      "city2": ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
      "city3": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
    },
    "region2": {
      "city1": ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
      "city2": ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
      "city3": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
    },
    "region3": {
      "city1": ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
      "city2": ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
      "city3": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
    }
  };
  for (let x in dropdown) {
    region.options[region.options.length] = new Option(x, x)
  };

  function one() {
    // empty city and theOptions dropdowns
    city.length = 1;
    theOptions.length = 1;
    // display values
    for (let y in dropdown[this.value]) {
      city.options[city.options.length] = new Option(y, y)
    }
  };

  function two() {
    // empty theOptions dropdown
    theOptions.length = 1;
    // display values
    let z = dropdown[region.value][this.value];
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      theOptions.options[theOptions.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i])
    }
  };

  // This is what I've tried to reach the third dropdown menu depending on the first (didn't work)
  function three() {
    // empty city and theOptions dropdowns
    city.length = 1;
    theOptions.length = 1;
    // display values
    let n = dropdown[this.value][city.value]; // I think the problem is here
    for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      theOptions.options[theOptions.options.length] = new Option(n[i], n[i])
    }
  };
  region.addEventListener("change", one)
  city.addEventListener("change", two)
  region.addEventListener("change", three)
});
```

```html
<select id="region">
  <option>ALL</option>
</select>
<select id="city">
  <option>ALL</option>
</select>
<select id="theOptions">
  <option>ALL</option>
</select>
```

What I want to say is that when I select for example "region3" I can choose from "theOptions" directly without choosing from the "city" (which will be "All")

Comment: The example you are sharing, is unclear. Don't forget you are also clearing the `theOptions` in both `one` and `two` changeHandlers (and interestingly, also in `three`). If they should all work independently from each other, maybe you could look at that first?

Comment: @Icepickle It was working fine until I added `three` to reach the third dropdown from the first one without choosing from the second one, I mean I should choose "ALL" from the second dropdown to view all the options for `region` and then choose from `theOptions`

Comment: If you select "region3" in the region dropdown, what options do you expect in the option dropdown? The values for your option dropdown are in the selected city. Which city is selected when you select "region3"?

Comment: @alexP yes now I understand, Thank you very much